# Joomla 3 menu modules not outputting

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

```
<jdoc:include type="module" name="topmenu" title="Top Nav" />
<jdoc:include type="module" name="mainmenu" title="Main Nav" />
```

I have these two modules that I included in my index.php  I have positions set up in my templateDetails.xml.   I have created main menu, assigned its module, and given that module the position of mainmenu.   I have added menu items yet nothing is output in that position.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I have added menu items...* you mean pages where to display the modules? If not check if your module settings have any menu items to be displayed in.

Comment: Is ther any html markup for this module? Are you sure your enabled the module? Would you be able to provide a link to the site?

Comment: The site is on localhost so no link unfortunately. No html is being output.  If I change the position of the module in /administrator to another position the links/markup are output.  So there is something wrong with my module/position name?

Comment: Are you also sure you're assigning the module to the position that belongs to your template? Cause there might be another template installed on your site with te same position name

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by changing jdoc:include type from module to modules.

I thought using module was for when you have one module that only ever lives in that position.  Was I mis-using it?  If so please tell me the proper way.

Comment: Modules is for when you import a position, module is when you import by name.